# incapsulating redis hmset in iced coffee script function

Tags: redis, iced-coffeescript

I want to incapsulate `redis hmset`.

```
exports.hmset = (name, autocb, params...)=>
    await client.hmset name, params, defer(err)
    throw err if err
```

I have that `params` is array like `['fooKey', 'fooValue', 'barKey', 'barValue']`. But then I have data in redis database on `name` key:

```
{'0' : 'fooKey', '1' : 'fooValue', '2' : 'barKey', '3': 'barValue'}
```

But I want it to be:

```
{'fooKey' : 'fooValue', 'barKey' : 'barValue'}
```

I understand that I have to pass them into `client.hmset` not like an array  `['fooKey', 'fooValue', 'barKey', 'barValue']` but just like  args:  `'fooKey', 'fooValue', 'barKey', 'barValue'`. But how to pass them through wrapping `exports.hmset` function when args length is various?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are using the [varargs](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#clienthmsethash-key1-val1--keyn-valn-callback) convention of calling `hmset`. You use a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) to collect the arguments in an array, and then you pass the array as an argument to node_redis -- which also supports the [object](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#clienthmsethash-obj-callback) convention, where you pass a plain object with the keys and their values. That's why you get your redis hash with positional keys, since if you treat a javascript array as an object, that's what you have.

What you need to do is simply to splat the `params` again when calling redis:

```
exports.hmset = (name, autocb, params...)=>
    await client.hmset name, params..., defer(err)
    throw err if err
```

Now, coffeescript will pass that array as varargs to the "real" `hmset`. As an added bonus, you can also still use the "params as an object" convention, which is arguably more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that `throw err` will not work in IcedCoffeeScript as you expect it to work?
It will raise error in an event loop, so that you could not catch it with "try" in your code.